# Xamarin forms customizable tabviews

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, path, tabs, skiasharp

[image]

Hello, how can i achieve this tab menu with FavTab transparent border (i don't know how to call it) in xamarin forms, using either xct `<xct:tabview></xct:tabview>`, sharpnado.tabs, paths, skiasharp (i don't know skia sharp much), i tried using xamarin community toolkit but i don't know how to craft the centered favtab in which it gives the transparent exactly like in the image, any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/170862/xamarin-bottom-custom-tab-bar.html

Comment: I see this is for Xamarin Shell, How can i make it work on Xamarin.Forms?

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/93f69d0e-1521-42cf-b8e6-6a83599a6eeb/tabbar-with-a-custom-button?forum=xamarinforms

Comment: I have seen a Solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64887786/xamarin-forms-cradle-fab by mr. @wizzyno https://stackoverflow.com/users/5381624/wizzyno

Comment: But still having Problems in the Android Parts.

Comment: What exactly is the problem in android part?

Comment: I solved it, i found out i didn't modify my theme as mr. wizzyno indicated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Yes, i was able to do it exactly as i want using Renderers like how mr. wizzyno gives here: [Xamarin.Forms - Cradle FAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64887786/xamarin-forms-cradle-fab) but make sure you modify the theme in your style to avoid the same mistake as mine. thanks for all your helps and mr wizzy for his help also
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q31xJ.png

Comment: Congrats.  Could you please mark it as answered so that it will help others who have similar problems? Thanks in advance. :)