# How can i add a Floating Action Button to bottom tabbar in .net MAUI?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, maui, .net-maui.shell

i need to create custome bottom tabbar to add a Floating Action Button, using .NET MAUI

like this picture:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxvvV.png)

i see this solution in the below link but it's for Xamarin.Forms and i can't using it with .NET MAUI

[Xamarin.Forms - Cradle FAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64887786/xamarin-forms-cradle-fab)

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/RadekVyM/Navbar-Animation-1

Answer (score 1):

Accoring to Shaw's comment, as an answer:

> i need to create custome bottom tabbar to add a Floating Action Button, using .NET MAUI

You can achieve it by this: [Navbar Animation](https://github.com/RadekVyM/Navbar-Animation-1).